# Invitation to ask/answer astronomy-related Bible questions

Tags: discussion

I know this may seem like an odd suggestion, but over at [Biblical Hermeneutic.SE](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/) we are running a [challenge](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/331/68) to ask new questions about astronomy in the Bible.  Like many [Ancient Near East](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Near_East) cultures, the Hebrews were fascinated with the movement of planets and watched the stars for signs of great import such as supernova and comets.  This interest in the sky carried over to the early Christians who used astronomical phenomena as symbols and signs of what they believed would soon happen.

To get an idea of the sort of questions we are looking for (and to see if you can provide answers to help us understand the Bible) take a look at the questions tagged with [astronomy](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astronomy).  We are generally open to all sorts of interpretations, but we do take the idea of understanding what the Bible means seriously.

So, do you have any questions about the Bible and/or have any answers for the questions we've already raised?  If so, come on over!

Comment: Thank you. I give tours of the night sky and often people ask religion-related questions.

Comment: Off topic. How is this related to Phys.SE? .

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about participation on another site.  (Not that there's anything wrong with that. ;-)  Also, the challenge has come and gone with little in the way of cross-over to show for it.

Comment: @Dimension10: Done and thanks for reminding me of this.

Comment: You could propose an ad here though: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2810/community-promotion-ads-2013.